# Referencing an external global variable from ReactJs app trough Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'd like to write a custom configuration block of code for my ReactJs application.
Right now my app is embedded like this:

```
<body>
   <section id="root"></section>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://somedomain.com/app-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

My app is going to be served on multiple domains so I can't load the config from the file as I don't have access to the embedded pages file systems 
I'd like to add config code something like this

```
<body>
    <script>
    let appConfig = {
    'config1':'value1',
    'config2':'value2'
    }
    </script>
<section id="root"></section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somedomain.com/app-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm not sure where and how should I reference the block of code within an application.
I have Webpack assembling my app with an entry and output fields defined like this

```
let config = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/index.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: assetsDir,
    filename: 'app-bundle.js'
  },
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to be able to access appConfig from within your app-bundle.js file that was created by webpack? If that's the case you can just do window.appConfig to access it.

Comment: Thanks window.appConfig does exactly what I need